# D3DX Font looking weird

Tags: c++, fonts, directx, d3dx

I am currently working on a small Engine, and therefore I use my own GUI-System I wrote a couple of months ago. Recently I updated it with some font options.

```
D3DXFONT_DESCA hFontCreationInfo = {
    hFontData.iFontSize,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    false,
    DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_CHARACTER_PRECIS,
    ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,
    TMPF_TRUETYPE,
    ""
};

strcpy(hFontCreationInfo.FaceName, hFontData.sBaseFontName);

HRESULT hrFont = D3DXCreateFontIndirect(gui->GetDevice(), &hFontCreationInfo, &m_hFont);
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: 12, 24 looks okay - but 16 is just buggy]

[image: this is size 12, also bugged]

So the question is, what am I doing wrong?

Freaky

Comment: Far too few pixels for the point size you annotated.  Looks like the output is getting scaled.  Either don't scale (best) or ask for a point size that is proportionally larger by the scaling amount.

Comment: I'm not scaling it.. (I also realized that if you look at size 16 it seems to be cut on the top - Any ideas?

My RECT calculations for DrawText look like this:
`RECT rct;
rct.left = x;
rct.right = x + w;
rct.top = y;
rct.bottom = y + h;`

And I calculate w,h (in the example) by calling DrawText with an empty rect (0,0,0,0) and DT_CALCRECT. You can see on the screenshot here that the calculations are right: http://puu.sh/6Yus4.png

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting truetype fonts with that call, so try using `OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS` instead of `OUT_CHARACTER_PRECIS` and then use `DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE` instead of `TMPF_TRUETYPE`. The quality parameter only applies to raster fonts anyway but you could use `CLEARTYPE_QUALITY` if you *do* want raster fonts.